# Array update statement blanks records in SQL table. - UPDATED

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sql-update

I have a database of recipes, on each you can edit the recipe and add remove ingredients and their quantities in a separate table.

I have an insert statement which works well for adding new items to my database.

But I want to adapt this for when I update recipes.  I have an update statement, but if I add new ingredients it needs to also Insert - similarly I need to remove any rows I delete.

I've adjusted my SQL statement and implode the array like I did for the original insert statement, however when I submit, it blanks all of the entries in the SQL table losing everything.

I've attached the whole code in case I'm approaching this wrong as I'm not sure that even mending this will give me the results I need.

```
$DishID=$_GET['DishID'];

$sql="UPDATE Dishes
      SET DishName='$DishName',
          DishCatID='$DishCatID',
          Serving='$Serving',
          SRP='$SRP',
          Method='$Method',
          SourceID='$SourceID'
      WHERE DishID='$DishID'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

$array = array('$DishID'=>$DishID,'$IngID'=>($_POST['IngID[]']),'$Volume'=>($_POST['Volume[]']) );

$values = array();
foreach ($_POST['IngID'] as $i => $ingID) {
    if (!empty($ingID)) {
        $ingID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $ingID);
        $volume = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Volume'][$i]);
        $values[] = "('$DishID', '$ingID', '$volume')";
    }
}
if (!empty($values)) {
    $sql2 = "UPDATE DishIng
             Set DishID=('$DishID'),
                 IngID= ('$IngID'),
                 Volume=('$Volume')";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql2) or die(mysqli_error($con));– 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your syntax use this code [mysql update manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

```
UPDATE DishIng Set DishID = 'xx', IngID = 'yy', Volume='zz'
```

and not use this code

```
UPDATE DishIng Set (DishID, IngID, Volume) VALUES
```